# Cannot clear URL history in Firefox 13 for OS X

Tags: macos, firefox, history

I use Firefox 13 in OS X. I can not clear my URL history after doing the following:

1. Running [Click & Clean](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/clickclean/) add-on for Firefox
2. *Tools » Clear Recent History*
3. OnyX for OS X, cleaning all Internet data
4. Reset Firefox itself through *Help » Troubleshooting Information*

Comment: Do you still see your history when going to *History » Show all history*, or does it still autocomplete URLs in the address bar when you enter them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try creating a new empty profile by opening *Applications/Terminal.app* and pasting:

```
/Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox-bin -profilemanager
```

Here, click *Create Profile*, enter a new profile name, then click *Start Firefox* to start with your new profile selected.

You can also delete your old profile – probably called *Default* – from the list if you want. Note that this will remove all of your data including history, saved passwords, add-ons, et cetera.

Comment: I tried /Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox-bin -Default for deleting old profile . it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Try [CCleaner for Mac](http://www.piriform.com/mac/ccleaner) and make sure everything is checked under `Applications tab / Firefox`:

[image]